# Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'AL-DMK2_1' to data type int

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures

For a stored procedure, I get the following exception/error.

> "Conversion failed when converting the varchar value `AL-DMK2_1` to data type int."

Stored procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.sp_generateNewRequestId
(
@Customer varchar(50),
@Network_Type varchar(25),
@Market_Name varchar(50),

@NewRequestId varchar(50) OUTPUT
)

AS

Begin

Declare @MarketCode as varchar(10);
Declare @CustomerPrefix as varchar(10);

SET @MarketCode = (select Market_Code from Customer_Market_Details where Customer =     @Customer and Network_Type = @Network_Type and Market_Name = @Market_Name);

SET @CustomerPrefix = (select Customer_Prefix from Customer_Market_Details where Customer = @Customer and Network_Type = @Network_Type and Market_Name = @Market_Name);

Declare @RequestIDPrefix as varchar(20);

SET @RequestIdPrefix =  @CustomerPrefix + @MarketCode + '_';

-- Count how many requests you already have with the same request ID Prefix.

Declare @RequestCount as int;

SET @RequestCount = (Select count (*) from request_details where request_id like   @RequestIdPrefix + '%');
SET @NewRequestId = @RequestIdPrefix + CAST ((@RequestCount + 1) AS varchar);

While (Exists (Select * from request_details where request_id = @NewRequestId ) )
Begin
SET @RequestCount = @RequestCount + 1;
SET @NewRequestId = @RequestIdPrefix + CAST ((@RequestCount + 1) AS varchar);
end

RETURN @NewRequestId;

END
```

Calling stored procedure:

```
    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["dbString"].ConnectionString))
    {
        using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("dbo.sp_generateNewRequestId", connection))
        {
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Customer", customer);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Network_Type", technology);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Market_Name", market);
            command.Parameters.Add("@NewRequestId", SqlDbType.VarChar).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
            command.Parameters["@NewRequestId"].Size = 50;
            command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            connection.Open();
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            connection.Close();
         }
    }
```

Observations:

when the output parameter is set to @RequestCount, the procedure successfully returns @RequestCount.

But if any other `varchar` value is attempted to output, the exception with the aforementioned error is thrown. The execution fails at the line `command.ExecuteNonQuery()`.

None of the solutions provided online worked for this error.
Appreciate your help!

Thanks!

Comment: What you have is a **SQL** error, not C#.  The error itself seems rather self-explanatory - you're trying to convert a `VARCHAR` that has letters to an `INT`.

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you return anything from a stored procedure, it must be able to be cast to an `int` as the return type of `SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()` is an `int` (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery.aspx) and the `RETURN` statement in SQL Server stored procs should only be use to return integer values (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174998.aspx), hence why `ExecuteNonQuery` has a return type of `int`, otherwise it would be `object`.

You're almost there, simply get rid of the return statement in the stored proc so it looks like this:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.sp_generateNewRequestId
(
@Customer varchar(50),
@Network_Type varchar(25),
@Market_Name varchar(50),

@NewRequestId varchar(50) OUTPUT
)

AS

Begin

Declare @MarketCode as varchar(10);
Declare @CustomerPrefix as varchar(10);

SET @MarketCode = (select Market_Code from Customer_Market_Details where Customer =     @Customer and Network_Type = @Network_Type and Market_Name = @Market_Name);

SET @CustomerPrefix = (select Customer_Prefix from Customer_Market_Details where Customer = @Customer and Network_Type = @Network_Type and Market_Name = @Market_Name);

Declare @RequestIDPrefix as varchar(20);

SET @RequestIdPrefix =  @CustomerPrefix + @MarketCode + '_';

-- Count how many requests you already have with the same request ID Prefix.

Declare @RequestCount as int;

SET @RequestCount = (Select count (*) from request_details where request_id like   @RequestIdPrefix + '%');
SET @NewRequestId = @RequestIdPrefix + CAST ((@RequestCount + 1) AS varchar);

While (Exists (Select * from request_details where request_id = @NewRequestId ) )
Begin
SET @RequestCount = @RequestCount + 1;
SET @NewRequestId = @RequestIdPrefix + CAST ((@RequestCount + 1) AS varchar);
end

END
```

And modify your C# code to this:

```
string newRequestID = "";

using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["dbString"].ConnectionString))
{
    using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("dbo.sp_generateNewRequestId", connection))
    {
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Customer", customer);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Network_Type", technology);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Market_Name", market);
        command.Parameters.Add("@NewRequestId", SqlDbType.VarChar).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
        command.Parameters["@NewRequestId"].Size = 50;
        command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        connection.Open();
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();

        newRequestID = (string)command.Parameters["@NewRequestId"].Value;

        connection.Close();
     }
}
```

Comment: As a side note, it's not strictly necessary to manually call `SqlConnection.Close()` inside of a `using` block as the dispose method does the same as close, or it calls close, or something like that.... Anyway it's not 100% needed if you want to save yourself a line of code =]

Comment: Just decompiled `System.Data` to find out which one it was. `Dispose` calls `Close`: `protected override void Dispose(bool disposing) { if (disposing) { this._userConnectionOptions = (DbConnectionOptions) null; this._poolGroup = (DbConnectionPoolGroup) null; this.Close(); } this.DisposeMe(disposing); base.Dispose(disposing); }`

Comment: Thanks!!! this worked well :)...and you raised a very important concept of SP RETURN statements.

Comment: for your close vs dispose comment, are you suggesting using Dispose() instead?

Comment: The `using` block calls `Dispose` for you, you'll notice how you can't use a `using` block with anything that doesn't implement the `IDisposable` interface. I should have been clearer with that =]